# Vaadin Grid DateRenderer not appliable

Tags: java, user-interface, web-applications, vaadin8

I have a Grid in a Vaadin application. For one column I want to apply a `DateRenderer`.
The following problem occurs:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? The [example](https://github.com/vaadin/book-examples/blob/master/src/com/vaadin/book/examples/component/grid/RendererExample.java) from the book of Vaadin is doing it like I do.

UPDATE

I got the same result as the answers to this question suggest. My working code (with several renderers):

```
final Grid<Signature> grid = new Grid<>(Signature.class);
grid.setSelectionMode(Grid.SelectionMode.SINGLE);
grid.setSizeFull();
grid.setColumns();
grid.addColumn("type").setCaption(bundle.getString("type"));
grid.addColumn("filename").setCaption(bundle.getString("filename"));
grid.addColumn("createdTime", new DateRenderer("%1$td.%1$tm.%1$tY %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS"))
        .setCaption(bundle.getString("creationDate"));
grid.addColumn(this::createCertificateLabel, new ComponentRenderer())
        .setCaption(bundle.getString("certificate"))
        .setDescriptionGenerator((DescriptionGenerator<Signature>) signature -> bundle.getString("certificateSerialNumber"));
grid.addColumn(this::createLink, new ComponentRenderer())
        .setCaption(bundle.getString("action"));
```

Comment: Please share your grid initialization code.

Comment: @Morfic I updated my question.

Comment: Already covered by Stefan, `Grid<Signature> grid = new Grid<>(Signature.class)`, instead of  `Grid grid = new Grid();` like in the linked example, is causing this. Due to the [date renderer definition `DateRenderer extends AbstractRenderer<Object, Date>`](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/ui/renderers/DateRenderer.java#L32) as well as [`public Column<T, V> setRenderer(Renderer<? super V> renderer)`](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.java#L2016), the inferred types don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at the signature: `Column<T, ?> getColumn(String columnId)`. It doesn't really know what's the second type parameter of your column because it could be anything. So applying a renderer by method `Column<T, V> setRenderer(Renderer<? super V> renderer)` expects an inferred renderer of type `Renderer<? super ?>` which I think can not be fulfilled.

**Solution 1:** Cast column to appropriate type like

```
((Grid.Column<YourBean, Date>) grid.getColumn("xyz")).setRenderer(new DateRenderer())
```

This will give you a compile warning due to unchecked cast. I think you could also cast to `Column` without type arguments but this will give you warnings, too.

**Solution 2:** As avix already pointed out in his answer, passing the renderer in the `addColumn` method is easier.

```
grid.addColumn(item -> someExpressionThatReturnsDate, new DateRenderer());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in `addColumn()` function which takes [AbstractRenderer](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/renderers/AbstractRenderer.html) while  `setRenderer()` excepts [Renderer](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/renderers/Renderer.html).

```
grid.addColumn( "myColumn", new DateRenderer( ... ) )
```

I guess you can also try doing it this way, but I haven't tested it (as `DateRenderer` implements `Renderer<Date>`):

```
column.setRenderer( (Renderer)new DateRenderer( ... ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got to the same solution. Because Steffen had some more details in his answer, I accepted his answer and upvoted yours.